# Cannot read property of '...' undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am a complete beginner in javascript and have the problem that my console.log won't output the return value of my function. Can someone explain this problem to me? Thanks for your help!

```
function convertFromHex(hex) {
  var hex = hex.toString();//force conversion
  var str = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
    str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
  return str;
}

function convertToHex(str) {
  var hex = '';
  for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {  // "cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error here
    hex += ''+str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
  }
  return hex;
}

console.log(convertToHex())  // "cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error here
```

Comment: `console.log(convertToHex())` You are calling the function which expects a parameter to be passed but you are not passing any.

Comment: U should pass a parameter to test `console.log(convertToHex("test"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
console.log(convertToHex())
```

your are not passing any parameter to `convertToHex`, and that function **expects** a parameter:

```
function convertToHex(str)
//                    ^^^
```

Now when you call that function like you did without passing an argument, `str` inside the function will be `undefined`.

And thus, here:

```
for(var i=0; i < str.length; i++)
//                 ^^^^
```

`undefined` has no `length`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing a string to your `convertToHex` function. As in:

```
console.log(convertToHex('42532'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(convertToHex())` needs a argument in your function.

If you dont add an argument you receive `cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error` here because JS dont know what have to convertToHex.

Answer (score 0):

your calling the function as console.log(convertToHex()) where your not passing any arguement to the function, hence the function recieves no value which is undefined and .length operation is not performed on an undefined value **str**

check with the below code

```
console.log(convertToHex('abcdef')) ;
```